# How to show that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon~\forall~x\in[a,b]?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed and bounded interval in $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b].$  How to show that for $\epsilon>0~\exists$ a piecewise **linear** continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon~\forall~x\in[a,b]?$

Help me! I'm clueless.

Comment: Is f a continuous function on [a,b] ?

Comment: For general $f$, this will not be possible.

Comment: sorry.........corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Since $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$, it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Then, there exists some $\delta>0$ so that

$$|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow  |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon \,.$$

Pick some integer $n>0$ so that $\frac{b-a}{n}<\delta$. Split the interval $[a,b]$ in $n$ equal subintervals, $[x_{i-1},x_i]$.

Let $g$ be the piecewise line which connects the points $(x_i,g(x_i)$. Prove that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Weierstrass's Theorem would give you that with $g$ being a polynomial.

-- Edit: no answering the question (it has been edited since).

Comment: The question has been edited since my answer.

Comment: @N.S. It's not his fault...I forgot to type 'linear'